# PostgreSQL: How to write a query for this scenario

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have this below table.

```
+_______+________+__________+________+
|Playid |billid|  amount    | Date   |
+_______+________+__________+________+
|123    | 345    | 144.9    | 2015-09|
|123    | 456    | 200      | 2015-10|
+_______+________+__________+________+
```

I need to write a query to show only the bill amount that has most recent transaction date (Date) like below.

```
+_______+________+__________+________+
|Playid |billid|  amount    | Date   |
+_______+________+__________+________+
|123    | 456    | 200      | 2015-10|
+_______+________+__________+________+
```

Please help me how do I do it.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar i tried using max (Date) with a case statement in select and having clause but its not working as expected.

Comment: @KushalLNU you have to accept one of the working answer instead of posting a "thanks" as an answer, just click on the mark below the voting arrows of the answer that solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

`MAX(Date)` can be used if you want to display only the `playid` and the most recent date.

**However,** The issue with what you are trying to do, is that you want to display all the columns. And this where the ranking functions come into play. In this case you can use the [`row_number` function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) like this:

```
SELECT PlayId, billid, amount, date
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    PlayId, billid, amount, date,
    row_number() over(partition by playid order by date dec) as rn
  FROM tablename
) t
where rn = 1
```

The `row_number() over(partition by playid order by date dec)` will give each group of `playid` a ranking number, the first one (the lowest one) will be the one with the most recent date. Then you just need to filter on the row number equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres offers `distinct on`.  This is simpler to write and often has the best performance:

```
select distinct on (playid) t.*
from t
order by playid, order by date desc;
```